# Change format and remove nanoseconds from Time in SSMS 18

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a table that will display employees' Shift Start and End times. Also, it will have the employees' Punch In and Punch Out times.

Is there a way to remove the nanoseconds and change the 24-hour Time format to AM/PM?  I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.

Comment: Any formatting of the `datetime` should be done at your front end application where the information is display

Comment: Tables contain data, not display data. The client app controls the data display format of all data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can format your datetime column using the [`format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(ShiftStartDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt')
FROM yourtable
```